# How do I use dm-tool switch-to-user from outside of dm session?

Tags: lightdm

I'm trying use `dm-tool switch-to-user` from outside of a session (I want to eventually call this from a systemd service)

I've followed the instructions on the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/dm-tool.1.html) on setting the `XDG_SEAT_PATH` variable.

I get this error:

```
# dm-tool list-seats
Seat0
  CanSwitch=true
  HasGuestAccount=false
# XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DesktopManager/Seat0 dm-tool switch-to-user kiosk
Unable to switch to user kiosk: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface ?org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.Seat? on object at path /org/freedesktop/DesktopManager/Seat0
```

System is Ubuntu 20.04

Can anyone help with how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The `XDG_SEAT_PATH` should be

/org/freedesktop/**Display**Manager/Seat0

And not

/org/freedesktop/**Desktop**Manager/Seat0

(This was [fixed](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/commit/6b9b538d76a52570df8f4999ff2e0c482913dd23) in the documentation recently.)

Comment: Great find! Thanks for documenting it here until the doc fix is propagated!